# Como escolher data no timestamp

Tags: php, data

Tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
round(microtime(true) * 1000)
```

com objetivo de pegar o timestamp em milissegundos da hora atual. Eu preciso pegar uma data futura, exemplo, 10 ou 5 minutos à frente. Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Talvez esta pergunta também possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841135/how-to-change-a-unix-timestamp-in-the-future-to-seconds-remaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é usar a [função](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-add.php) `DateTime::add`:

```
$dataQualquer = new DateTime();
$dataQualquer->add(new DateInterval('PT10M')); // 10 minutos no futuro
echo 'Timestamp:'.$dataQualquer->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `time` do PHP, que retorna o time em segundos.

```
<?php
// time atual em segundos
$now = time();
// adicionando 5 minutos
$futuro5min = $now + (5*60);
// adicionando 10 minutos
$futuro = $now + (10*60);
?>
```

Lembrando que o timestamp está em segundos. Para obter em milisegundos, basta multiplicar o resultado final por 1000.

http://php.net/time